# Automatic <p> tags?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a "Public Profile" page, which shows infomation about users, but I have a certain one which is (Tidl poster) which automaticly adds an paragraph around it.

I've already tried looking up the code, and strip html tags, this does not help tho.

```php
<?php if ( ! empty( $member['tidligere_poster'] ) ) : ?>
    <?php
    $text = strip_tags($member['tidligere_poster']);
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trophy"></i> Tidl. Poster</span>
            <input type="textarea" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" class="form-control" height="10px" disabled>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want it to show up without the `<p>` tag, how do i achieve this?

Comment: nothing in the code you are showing is demonstrating your issue. Please post the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try html_entity_decode with strip_tags on this Code.

```
          <?php if ( ! empty( $member['tidligere_poster'] ) ) : ?>
               <?php  $text = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($member['tidligere_poster'])); ?>  
                      <div class="form-group">                     
                           <div class="input-group">                                  
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trophy"></i> Tidl. Poster</span>
                                 <input type="textarea" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" class="form-control" height="10px" disabled>
                           </div>
                       </div>
         <?php endif; ?>
```